How to remove Default Splash Screen in flutter
So i have created a splash screen by using flutter widgets but when i run my app it will show the default splash screen which has flutter icon in center then my splash screen is showing ,
Is someOne Help me to remove default splash screen from from app
I tried flutter_native_splash package but it does not add any animaitons in my splash screen so i also use animated_splash_screen pakage but i cant remove the deafult one!

use flutter_native_splash package

Are you running this in an emulator or on a real device? (Sometimes the emulators do weird things with splash screens).

You can remove default splash screen in Android 12 & Above by writing <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item> in your android/app/res/values/themes.xml but it's not right way. Also see this answer

Thanks for the suggestion!
I understand that you can remove the default splash screen in Android 12 and above by adding <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item> to android/app/res/values/themes.xml. However, I’ve heard that this might not be the best approach.
Is there a recommended way to properly handle or remove the splash screen in Android 12 and above? Any best practices or alternative methods would be greatly appreciated!

The mobile operating systems cannot animate something to replace that static picture. Any animation you see is happening after the equivalent of main() starting up in Flutter. You can replace the screen before main() with a static picture, which is what package:flutter_native_splash does.

Thanks for the information!
I understand that the mobile operating systems cannot animate something to replace the static picture shown before main() starts up in Flutter.
I’m aware that the flutter_native_splash package can replace the screen before main() with a static picture. However, I'm looking for a way to remove or hide the entire splash screen altogether.
Is there a method to achieve this, or is it necessary to use a static image as the splash screen? Any additional insights would be appreciated!

The operating system is performing loading operations during that time.  You cannot make that time go away.  That's the point of the splash screen... to have something visible while the OS is getting your app initialized.

I understand that the splash screen is necessary due to loading operations before app initialization. However, many apps use custom splash screens and remove the default one.
Is it possible to:

Customize the splash screen with your own design?
Remove or hide the default splash screen?

Could you provide details on how this can be done in Flutter? I'm interested in methods or packages for replacing or customizing the splash screen.

It's possible to completely replace the native splash screen (a static image) with flutter_native_splash package (replacing with another static image).  Not sure why I need to keep repeating this.

But i don't want to use flutter_native_splash package i make it with dart but default one i cant remove can you help me to remove it do you know how to remove it i try this
https://chatgpt.com/share/66e6636f-2d10-800c-ba93-11f8b8a16030

when the answer to "how do I do X" is "use Y" but your response is "I don't want to use Y", I cannot help further unless you explain why.  Good luck on your task.
